# Bundle = getIntent().getExtras() is always null

Tags: android, android-intent, extras

I'm writing an alarm app. When I save the alarm, it's displayed in a ListView in my MainActivity.
When I want to click the row and edit that reminder, the `getIntent().getExtras()` is always null, so I have no value to go back to

This is my MainActivity

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmChooser.class));

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(row==null || row.getTag()==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResource,null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();

            holder.mTitle=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.mDate=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
            holder.mTime=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.timeText);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        holder.myAlarm = getItem(position);
        holder.mTitle.setText(holder.myAlarm.getTitle());
        holder.mDate.setText(holder.myAlarm.getRecordDate());
        holder.mTime.setText(holder.myAlarm.getRecordTime());

        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.mTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    String titles = extras.getString("title");
                    int day = extras.getInt("day");
                    int month = extras.getInt("month");
                    int year = extras.getInt("year");
                    int minute = extras.getInt("minute");
                    int hour = extras.getInt("hour");
      String typeee = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_TYPE));

                    Log.e("title", titles);

                    Log.e("year", "value=" + year);
                    Log.e("month", "value=" + month);
                    Log.e("day", "value=" + day);
                    Log.e("hour", "value=" + hour);
                    Log.e("minute", "value=" + minute);
                    Log.e("type", typeee);

                    Class next = null;

                    switch (typeee) {
                        case "TimeDateRem":
                            next = TimeDateRem.class;
                            break;
                        case "BirthdayRem":
                            next = BirthdayRem.class;
                            break;
                        case "HolidayReminderKuwait":
                            next = HolidayReminderKuwait.class;
                            break;
                        case "HolidayReminderLebanon":
                            next = HolidayReminderLebanon.class;
                            break;
                        case "HolidayReminderSaudiArabia":
                            next = HolidayReminderSaudiArabia.class;
                            break;
                        case "HolidayReminderUAE":
                            next = HolidayReminderUAE.class;
                            break;
                    }

                    if (next != null) {
                        Intent return_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, next);
                        return_intent.putExtra("alarm_title", titles);
                        return_intent.putExtra("alarm_month", month);
                        return_intent.putExtra("alarm_year", year);
                        return_intent.putExtra("alarm_day", day);
                        return_intent.putExtra("alarm_hour", hour);
                        return_intent.putExtra("alarm_minute", minute);
                        //   next_intent.putExtra("alarm_content", contenttt);
                        return_intent.putExtra("FROM_ACTIVITY", "MainActivity");
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, return_intent);
                        finish();

  } else {

                    Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR");
                }

});

        return row;

}
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        MyAlarm myAlarm;
        TextView mTitle;
        TextView mDate;
        TextView mTime;
        TextView mContent;
        TextView mID;
    }
}
```

And this is my TimeDateRem, which is an alarm where im tring to get the data from - unsucessfully

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_view);

    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {
  Intent intent_ForResult = new Intent(TimeDateRem.this, MainActivity.class);
           intent_ForResult.putExtra("title", title.getText().toString().trim());
    intent_ForResult.putExtra("day", pickerDate.getDayOfMonth());
    intent_ForResult.putExtra("month", pickerDate.getMonth());
    intent_ForResult.putExtra("year", pickerDate.getYear());
    intent_ForResult.putExtra("hour", pickerTime.getCurrentHour());
    intent_ForResult.putExtra("minute", pickerTime.getCurrentMinute());
    intent_ForResult.putExtra("type", "TimeDateRem");
   startActivityForResult(intent_ForResult, REQUEST);
  }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String previousActivity = extras.getString("FROM_ACTIVITY");

            if (previousActivity.equals("MainActivity")) {

                String titles = extras.getString("alarm_title");
                int year_intent = extras.getInt("alarm_year");
                int month_intent = extras.getInt("alarm_month");
                int day_intent = extras.getInt("alarm_day");
                int minute_intent = extras.getInt("alarm_minute");
                int hour_intent = extras.getInt("alarm_hour");

                String year = String.valueOf(year_intent);
                String month = String.valueOf(month_intent);
                String day = String.valueOf(day_intent);
                String minute = String.valueOf(minute_intent);
                String hour = String.valueOf(hour_intent);

                title.setText(titles);
                pickerTime.setCurrentHour(Integer.parseInt(hour));
                pickerTime.setCurrentMinute(Integer.parseInt(minute));
                pickerDate.init(
                        Integer.parseInt(year),
                        Integer.parseInt(month),
                        Integer.parseInt(day),
                        null
                );

                String result = data.getStringExtra("returnData");
                Log.e("RESULTRESULRESULT ", result);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is getting the data from the TimeDateRem, sending it to main Activity and then sending it back to TimeDateRem.
If I want to edit the saved reminder, but `bundle somthing = getIntent().getExtras()` always returns null...

Comment: This code doesn't compile... You have a method within a method

Comment: what do you mean by doesnt compile.. which part @cricket_007

Comment: its not my full code just what i needed help with

Comment: You don't need the full code, but you do need a [mcve]. This is isn't minimal or complete, and there isn't verifiable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `getIntent()` instead of the `Intent data`... So, that's not the intent that you have passed via `startActivityForResult`

For example

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            String previousActivity = extras.getString("FROM_ACTIVITY");
```

Also, if `getIntent().getExtras()` works outside of the click event, then make it a field.

```
private Bundle extras;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .... 
    this.extras = getIntent().getExtras();
}
```

And use those in the onClick

Ideally, though, I'd suggest not defining the entire adapter within the Activity code and instead create a separate class file. In which case, you cannot use the Activity Intent within the adapter code

Comment: thank you that was very helpfull but what about the bundle in my MainActivity... nothing has changed there @cricket_007

Comment: This code I copied looks like it is in the MainActivity. I don't under the question

Comment: Why are you finishing the MainActivity? Don't you want to **start** the DateTimeRem activity? Then getIntent will work correctly...

Comment: no the code you just corrected  is in my TimeDateRem.. the one in my main activity is         holder.mTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (extras != null) { ...    @cricket_007

Comment: And I've tried to explain that you  shouldn't mix the adapter ViewHolder class with the Activity intent...

Comment: wow..rookie mistake i just saw that but still .. i dont even get to that part of the code ... if(extras!=null) is always = null o i never even get there @cricket_007

Comment: `getIntent()` only has extras if you set them from a previous usage of `startActivity`, not `setResult`. Does that make sense?

Comment: come to think of it i can use both set result and startActivity there@cricket_007 and i dont think id be able to use the adapter the exact way im using it if it were in another class file

Comment: I think you're confusing when you need to use either method. One starts a new Activity (and uses getIntent), the other quits the current Activity and returns the results back to the Activity that called `startActivityForResult`. When you use setResult, then that is the `Intent data` parameter

Comment: exactly... so when i call startActivityForResult(intent_ForResult, REQUEST); in my TimeDateRem...all should be good when i call Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); in my MainActivity ... but its not the bundle is null, or is that related to the viewholder and adapter like u said...thank you for bearing with me @cricket_007

Comment: I don't think MainActivity ever loads the adapter. You'll call startActivity immediately in onCreate... My point about the adapter is that each row of the listview is seeing the exact same intent and getting the exact same data, which probably is not what you want.

Comment: lol no my listview is fine my code works its just when i click on a row...everything crashes...clicking on the row is supposed to edit the row(reminder) @cricket_007

Comment: By definition, if everything crashes, it isn't fine. It may display okay, but the click event does not look correct to me. I would suggest that you set breakpoints and debug the intent data and other variables

Comment: again..my code works fine..everything is fine until i click a row...i always get the Error Error Log in the else{} that i wrote for if(extras!=null) so yet again...only the bundle being null is what i care about and i guess i wont find an answer here but thank you anyway u were helpfull @cricket_007

Comment: I would answer in more detail if you provided the actual stacktrace and a [mcve] in your question

Comment: just help me answer this...in my mainactivity...why do i get the values if i use getIntent() in the OnCreate ,and i  get null in an OnClick() outside oncreate @cricket_007

Comment: and there is no error in my stacktrace just the ERROR ERROR log that you can see in the else of if(extras!=null) thats why i ddnt post it because its basically useless and i have many loggs i ddnt post that would just be confusing @cricket_007

Comment: did the trick..thank you @cricket_007 one last question and ill get out of your shoes...setResult() doesnt send me back to the other activity..it just stays there..and if i call finish after it it just kills the activity and goes nowhere...any thoughts?

Comment: The finish method should go back. Feel free to create a new post with that problem

Answer (score 0):

You are putting data to intent directly and accessing using bundle, which is wrong. Use data.getString directly. You have to set bundle to intent like intent.setExtras(bundle) if you want to get it using `data.getExtras()` in `onActivityResult`

Comment: setExtras(bundle) does not exist for and Intent class

Comment: My bad,  putExtras not setExtras

Comment: true but what about the other one in the onclick of the main activity...bundle is null there too @user12345